# Define a new operation $*$ on $G$ by $a * b = ac^{-1} b$

Tags: group-theory

Let $G$ be a group and let $c$ be a fixed element of $G$.
Define a new operation $*$ on $G$ by 
$$a * b = ac^{-1} b$$

I already show the associativity: for $a,b,d\in G$,
$$\begin{align*}
a * (b*d)
&= a*(bc^{-1} d)\\
&=ac^{-1}(bc^{-1}d)\\
&=(ac^{-1})(bc^{-1}d).\\
(a * b)*d&=(ac^{-1} b)*d\\
&=(ac^{-1}b)c^{-1}d\\
&=(ac^{-1})bc^{-1}d\\
&=(ac^{-1})(bc^{-1}d)\\
&=a * (b*d)
\end{align*}$$
and find the identity is $c$, how do I find the inverse?

Comment: How did you prove associativity? Could you include this into your post?

Comment: This looks interesting. Where does it come from?

Comment: @RobArthan It from my textbook "Number, Groups and Codes"

Answer (score 4):

Hint: solve the equation $ac^{-1}x = c$ for $x$ and then check that also gives a solution to $xc^{-1}a = c$.

> The solution is $x = ca^{-1}c$

Aside: I now see how this arises. If you define $f : G\to G$ by $f(x) = c^{-1}x$, then $f$ is a bijection and you get a new group operation on $G$ by using $f$ to relabel the elements of $G$. Thus:
$$
a * b = f^{-1}(f(a)f(b)) = c((c^{-1}a)(c^{-1}b)) = ac^{-1}b
$$

Comment: This is a very good answer. The exercise as is posted is empty, just calculations. But the observation that this is a relabeling via $f$ make it interesting and one understands what's behind the exercise.